# Warning - Unknown call: "relay:check" in react-native iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-navigation, babeljs

I'm getting this warning on the home screen of my iOS app which is built in React Native. Below are my dependencies in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "pretty-format": "^23.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.0.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.16",
    "react-navigation": "^^2.5.5",
    "react-relay": "^1.7.0",
    "react-timestamp": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
```

[image: React native ios warning relay:check]

Comment: Did you have enabled remote debugging ???

Comment: Yes I do. Is there part of the debug which I should look at?

Comment: I am asking you about that because i think that the warning must diseappear if you disable remote debugging as it was my case.what i mean that this warnung can be ignored because it is just show while remote debugging is enabled and will not affect production version.Maybe it is somethin related to the connection between device and the remote server which run the app

Comment: For more info check it here : https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1233

Comment: I saw that thread on github. Let's assume you are correct.  I can disable remote debugging and I won't see the warning.  But that isn't solving the issue when developing and I need remote debugging enabled.

Answer (score 1):

do you use React Native Debugger?

I also get that warning while using react native debugger and after updating the react native debugger the warning disapear.
So, try to update your debugger to the latest version.

Comment: I do. I have updated it recently. I need to refresh my memory on this.  It has been a few months.